# Не могу решить проблему с MessageSource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

В моём приложении вылетает ошибка:

```
NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'Size.userForm.username.userForm.username' for locale 'ru_RU
```

Вот сам файл validation.properties:

```
Required=This field is required.
Size.userForm.username=Username must be between 8 and 32 characters.
Duplicate.userForm.username=Such username already exists.
Size.userForm.password=Password must be over 8 characters.
Different.userForm.password=Password don't match.
```

Его настройка в SpringMVC:

```
@Bean
    public MessageSource getMessageSource(){
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:validation");
        messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
        return messageSource;
    }
```

Класс валидатор:

```
@Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        User user = (User) o;
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "username", "Required");
        if (user.getUsername().length() < 8 || user.getUsername().length() > 32)
            errors.rejectValue("username", "Size.userForm.username");
        if (userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) != null)
            errors.rejectValue("username", "Duplicate.userForm.username");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "Required");
        if (user.getPassword().length() < 8 || user.getPassword().length() > 32)
            errors.rejectValue("password", "Size.userForm.password");
        if (!user.getConfirmPassword().equals(user.getPassword()))
            errors.rejectValue("confirmPassword", "Different.userForm.password");
    }
```

И jsp страница:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Create new account</title>

    <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="userForm" class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create your account</h2>
        <spring:bind path="username">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <form:input type="text" path="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"
                            autofocus="true"></form:input>
                <form:errors path="username"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>

        <spring:bind path="password">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <form:input type="password" path="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"></form:input>
                <form:errors path="password"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>

        <spring:bind path="confirmPassword">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <form:input type="password" path="confirmPassword" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Confirm your password"></form:input>
                <form:errors path="confirmPassword"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form:form>

</div>
<!-- /container -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Пробовал добавлять к файлу _ru_RU не помогает, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Size.userForm.username.userForm.username - не увидел у Вас данной мессаги

Comment: @GenCloud в том то и дело что ее нет